# Loading TIMESTAMP data in a file into IBM Db2 on Cloud

Tags: db2

I am loading a data into IBM cloud and it has a date and time format that looks like this, 08/28/2004 05:50:56 PM. what would be the correct time format? i have tried given available formats but they do not match. If i need to create one, how do i go about it? Thank you.

Comment: How do you try to load the data - LOAD utility / Import / Insert? Which OS?

Comment: Import. OS is windows 10. I have the data downloaded from a website then i load it into my schema on DB2 on IBM cloud

Comment: Basically using the load data procedure on DB2 in IBM Cloud. The data is loaded from my computer

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the Db2 Console for Db2 on Cloud currently uses LOAD statements to get data into Db2.  The Db2 Console for Db2 *Warehouse*on Cloud uses both LOAD  and EXTERNAL TABLE (for Netezza/PDA sourced data)

The timestamp format options for LOAD are less flexible than those available with EXTERNAL TABLE based loads in Db2 11.5

You need to use this format

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS TT
```

as per the available elements listed under the `timestampformat` option on this page https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html

Here is an client command line example.

```
$ cat file.csv
08/28/2004 05:50:56 PM
$ db2 "create table ts(ts timestamp)"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

$ db2 'import from file.csv of del modified by timestampformat="MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS TT" insert into ts'
SQL3109N  The utility is beginning to load data from file "file.csv".

SQL3110N  The utility has completed processing.  "1" rows were read from the 
input file.

SQL3221W  ...Begin COMMIT WORK. Input Record Count = "1".

SQL3222W  ...COMMIT of any database changes was successful.

SQL3149N  "1" rows were processed from the input file.  "1" rows were 
successfully inserted into the table.  "0" rows were rejected.


Number of rows read         = 1
Number of rows skipped      = 0
Number of rows inserted     = 1
Number of rows updated      = 0
Number of rows rejected     = 0
Number of rows committed    = 1

$ db2 "select * from ts"

TS                        
--------------------------
2004-08-28-17.50.56.000000

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
values to_date('08/28/2004 05:50:56 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
```

So, try this format.

Comment: Okay let me try that.

Comment: Okay i ran that and it ran correctly but it neither changed the data timestamp format or give me that timestamp format when i tried to load the data again.

Comment: The issue here is as soon as DB2 loads the data (this is the web address to download the data i'm taking about https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/svflyugsr9zbqy5bmowgswqemfpm1x7f.csv), part of its loading procedure is to give you an option to choose a timestamp format if the data format does not match that of DB2. Now there is where the main challenge is because the data has the format DD/MM/YYYY  HH:MM:SS:TT where TT refers to either AM or PM. Getting the right format is the problem because any other format results in the whole data being deleted by DB2.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a way, which this procedure uses to run data loads internally. You should either check if it's possible at all to change such a timestamp format there, or convert your data to the format expected by this tool...

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help. I finally found the solution. To create a new timestamp format, click inside the timestamp format field and hit SPACE to blank the current selection. THEN TYPE IN

[ MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS TT ]

Without the brackets.

Hit next and continue to import. “